# What does the green box in front of the C# tag mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

So, I follow C# and starting from today I can see a green box before the tag as follows:

[image]

What does it mean, and why do I see it? I am just curious!

Comment: I'm not a fan of downvoting for lack of research on meta in general but... considering this was posted elsewhere and moved here... it seems even less warranted. This is a valid report, please, let's not penalize them for being second to meta.